# DC Jenkins server to AWS servers connection

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, vpn

We are trying to automate the deployment process for our application, our application has two components (one hosted on DC, one hosted on AWS). 
Now, we are not sure how do we connect the jenkins from our DC to the AWS environment hosted servers using VPN or is there any way by which the connection can be established.

P.S: We cannot install a new jenkins in the EC2 instance directly and do the deployment there, as we would need to pull the source code for the build to the cloud layer which is not acceptable by our compliance team.

Comment: If you're using a VPN in AWS, does your build environment have a route to it? Can you be a bit more specific in the kind of errors you're having?

Comment: Thanks @BruceBecker for the comment, we are searching how to establish a route to it. Am looking for options on the ways to connect to AWS servers using VPN from the Build server

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use-case, you should look either:

- Establishing a persistent VPN connection to the AWS VPC using the Site-To-Site VPN as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html
- Using an OpenVPN client via the build jobs using the client VPN service as  described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html